# Why does Javascript alert pops up only numbers and not strings?

Tags: javascript, php, alert

Can anyone help me understanding why:

```
<?php $x = 'b'; ?>
<script> var v=<?php echo $x;?>;  alert(v);</script>
```

does not pop up an alert whereas

```
<?php $x = '3'; ?>
<script> var v=<?php echo $x;?>;  alert(v);</script>
```

does pop up an alert with the text 3?

Answer (score 7):

You're echoing a single letter `b` into your script element, which results in:

```
<script> var v=b;  alert(v);</script>
```

This is an identifier as far as JavaScript is concerned, not a string. Since the JavaScript variable `b` isn't defined, an error occurs, and nothing is alerted.

When you echo a 3:

```
<script> var v=3;  alert(v);</script>
```

What JavaScript sees is a number literal 3, which it has no problem assigning and alerting.

Comment: @mohamedrias: But he _didn't_ do that.

Answer (score 3):

Always look at the rendered output.

```
<script> var v = 3; alert(v); </script>
```

vs.

```
<script> var v = b; alert(v); </script>
```

To reliably pass a PHP variable into JavaScript, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-output)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php $x = '3'; ?>
<script> var v='<?php echo $x;?>';  alert(v);</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically PHP code runs at the server side before the page loads and Javascript starts executing after the script in the page loads.

So as per your code

```
<?php $x = 'b'; ?>
<script> var v=<?php echo $x;?>;  alert(v);</script>
```

When that code is resolved at the server side , the php values would have been filled in the script tags.

it will be like

```
<script> var v=b;  alert(v);</script>
```

Now when the page is rendered at the client. Once this line is executed, javascript starts looking at the variable b. In terms of PHP it was a string but in terms of javascript its a variable as it's not enclosed by double quotes.

As javascript doesn't find any variable named b , it throws b is undefined error.

Now when it comes to number:

```
<?php $x = '3'; ?>
<script> var v=<?php echo $x;?>;  alert(v);</script>
```

In the client this will be rendered as

```
<script> var v=3;  alert(v);</script>
```

Now as it's just a number and not a variable. Javascript doesn't throw any error.

if you want the string to work in javascript then,

add quotes for b inside the php variable

```
    <?php $x = '"b"'; ?>
    <script> var v=<?php echo $x;?>;  alert(v);</script>
```

Now even PHP strings will give alert

Answer (score 0):

Your generated javscript is lacking the enclosing quotes or the literal value. therefore the assignment `var v=...` runs into an error *unless* the assigned value is a number.

use

```
<script> var v="<?php echo $x;?>";  alert(v);</script>
```

instead to see all output (but beware of double quotes in `$x`).